# python 3 saving a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have looked at other questions on SO like this one but they are too techy for me to understand (only been learning a few days).
I am making a phonebook and i am trying to save a dictionary like so,

```
numbers = {}
def save(a):
   x = open("phonebook.txt", "w")
   for l in a:
       x.write(l, a[l])
   x.close()
```

But i get error write() only takes 1 argument and obv im passing 2, so my question is how can i do this in a beginner freindly way and could you describe it in a non techy way.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What output format do you expect?

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy you should remove that comment; horrible advice.

Comment: beginner friendly :) but fair enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to use [json](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module for dumping/loading dictionary to/from a file:

```
>>> import json
>>> numbers = {'1': 2, '3': 4, '5': 6}
>>> with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as f:
...     json.dump(numbers, f)
>>> with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
...     print json.load(f)
... 
{u'1': 2, u'3': 4, u'5': 6}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but could you explain 'with' and 'as f' . And i take it .dump is .write and .load is .read

Comment: @PaulRice sure, [with](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is a context manager, shortcut that replaces `try: except: finally:` boilerplate code. `dump` is write, `load` is read, right.

Comment: Ok great help. Thanks .. One last thing how do i close it after or is it not needed

Comment: @PaulRice that's the point, it closes it automatically. Python is beautiful, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 5):

While JSON is a good choice and is cross-language and supported by browsers, Python has its own serialization format called pickle that is much more flexible.

```
import pickle

data = {'Spam': 10, 'Eggs': 5, 'Bacon': 11}

with open('/tmp/data.pickle', 'w') as pfile:
    pickle.dump(data, pfile)

with open('/tmp/data.pickle', 'r') as pfile:
    read_data = pickle.load(pfile)

print(read_data)
```

Pickle is Python-specific, doesn't work with other languages, and be careful to never load pickle data from untrusted sources (such as over the web) as it's not considered "safe".

Pickle works for other data types too, including instances of your own classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `json` module and `JSONEncode` your dict, then you can use the module to write the new object to file.

When you read the file, you need to `JSONDecode` to convert it back into a python dict.

```
>>> import json
>>> d = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
>>> d
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
>>> json.JSONEncoder().encode(d)
'{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}'
>>> with open('phonebook.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.JSONEncoder().encode(d))

>>> with open('phonebook.txt', 'r') as f:
    print f.readlines()

['{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3}']
```

Comment: It's generally simpler to just use the `json.dump()` and `json.load()` functions. Like `json.dump(d, f)` to write, and `json.load(f)` to read.